# Sprite Animation Management Using Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, animation

I'm in the process of creating my own two-dimensional game.  Every object in the game world has a Sprite object, and when the screen is drawn, the object's sprite is drawn in the object's location.

The sprite class can be either a single image or a series of images used to make an animates sprite.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
public class Sprite implements Runnable{
    private int currentImage;   
    private BufferedImage[] sprites;
    private int delayMS;
    private Thread animation;

    public Sprite(BufferedImage sprite){
        sprites = new BufferedImage[1];
        sprites[0] = sprite;
    }

    public Sprite(BufferedImage[] spriteAnimation,int delay){
        this.sprites = spriteAnimation;
        currentImage = 0;
        delayMS = delay;
        //start a thread to time animation
        animation = new Thread(this);
        animation.start();
    }

    private void next(){
        if(currentImage < sprites.length - 1)
            currentImage++;
        else
            currentImage = 0;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (Thread.currentThread() == animation) {
            //delay the animation for delayMS
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delayMS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
            //next image
            next();
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g,int x,int y){
        g.drawImage(sprites[currentImage],null,x,y);
    }
}
```

I couldn't find any reliable information on the subject of using threads to run many animations, and I was wondering whether this was the best approach.
Everything works great until I throw 200ish identical objects into the world. FPS begins to lower and some animated sprites begin to change frames at different times.  This would make sense since the threads would start to delay when instantiated.

My questions is whether there is a more efficient way to handle this, allowing me to use more objects without significant FPS loss, and synchronize the thread/threads so that the animations switch frames together.

Comment: i don't know about animation, but i do know about threading.  you must make the currentImage member var volatile so that updates will be seen between the various threads.  also, starting a Thread in a constructor is almost always a bad design (if i ever want to subclass this class, the Thread will start before the class is fully constructed).  use a static helper method to create the class and start the thread (after fully constructed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way of doing this is to have a game loop that knows all the sprites and calls a draw method on them (or preferably only those that needs be redrawn) for each frame. This way, whenever a sprite decides it wants to animate, it will not do so until the next frame. Just do the animating the the draw method, e.i. the next() part.
And of course, in the game loop you put your delay, which will determine the fps.

To get frame rate independent animation you do the same but add an argument to the draw method which says how much time has passed since the last draw, then calculate the amount of animation based on this.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying that before I saw something about threads, and I should have stuck with it. Works a lot better. Luckily I was using the time between frames for physics, so I just had to modify the parameters for the sprite class and I was on my way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running every sprite on its own thread, you could put the sprites on a container, and on a rendering thread iterate through all visible sprites and draw them (you could even implement sprite priorities, render background layers before sprites, ...).

Answer (score 0):

if you use more threads for sprites (i.e, one thread for one sprite) then it will eat your cpu and it will hang the best way to implement animation in games is for every run loop of thread do change the animation sequences ( like next image or previous upon key Presses) and paint the sprites at the end. 
Here if it is more sprites and paint will take more time then FPS will drop at the time two or three threads max with synchronization